# How to remove trailing space in output file

Tags: batch-file

This is my first post to this site, though I use it quite often.  I wrote a batch file to do the following, ideally.  Note: There are alot of echos in here, to help me debug.

1.) Clean up old log files, this works file
2.) Ping a list of systems and output successful results to one file and bad to another
3.) Check if software exists, if not download it
4.) Install software on endpoint

The issue I am encountering is the successful ping output files has trailing spaces.  Because of this, the install commands don't work.  It puts the trailing space in the UNC path.  Since the spaces exist, the run command doesn't work.

HELP PLEASE, My desk is breaking, due to my forehead smashing into it.

---

```
@echo off

cls

set file=_0_Add_Systems_Here.txt
set log1=_3_Responsive.txt
set log2=_4_Non-Responsive.txt
set dir=%cd%
FOR /F "usebackq" %%i IN (`hostname`) DO SET host=%%i

echo Run Cleanup
start _2_Dont_Run_Me.bat

echo Ping
for /F "tokens=*" %%a in (%file%) do @ping %%a | find "TTL=" > nul && echo %%a >> %log1% || echo %%a >> %log2%

echo Output systems
for /F "tokens=*" %%a in (%log1%) do echo "%%a"

echo Check for Framepkg
if not exist framepkg.exe Copy \\<Removed>\c$\MFE\framepkg.exe | echo copying frame package.
if exist framepkg.exe echo Found frame package.

echo copy framepackage to system
for /F "tokens=*" %%b in (%log1%) do copy %dir%\framepkg.exe \\%%b\c$\framepkg.exe /y >> _5_McAfee_Deployment_Output.txt
for /F "tokens=*" %%b in (%log1%) do echo \\%%b\c$\framepkg.exe

echo start agent install
for /F "tokens=*" %%c in (%log1%) do psexec \\%%c cmd /c "c:\framepkg.exe /install=agent /forceinstall" >> \\%host%\%dir%\_5_McAfee_Deployment_Output.txt
```

---

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
....&& >>%log1% echo %%a||>>%log2% echo %%a
```

should fix your problem (the extra spaces in your code appear to cause the problem; the redirector location within the statement is not relevant - first is as good as last)

OR

```
....&& echo %%a\ >> %log1% || echo %%a\ >> %log2%
```

AND

```
for /F "delims=\" %%b in (%log1%)....
```

but that would place extra `\` in your log files.

(reason for `\` is that it can't exist in valid data)